# delphi tedit physical keyboard

Tags: delphi, keyboard

I'm developing an Android-app with Delphi XE6, which should (also) run on Blackberry OS10 with physical keyboards (Q10, PassPort) (by sideloading the APK-file). The whole application works fine on Q10, except for the TEdit-controls. TEdit-controls jsut won't accept input from the physical keyboard. The strange thing however is that the functions InputBox and InputQuery DO work, and they use TEdits too.

Even the simplest application (1 TEdit, 1 Button which calls InputBox) does only work for InputBox, TEdit does not receive input from the physical keyboard.

Comment: AFAIK, you are the first person to actually test Delphi Android apps on Blackberry phones, so can you visit the following Delphi wiki page and run the test projects and post your results for future reference: [Android Devices Supported for Application Development](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development). There are already slots created for the various Blackberry models (near the bottom of the page), they just need to be filled in.

Answer (score 0):

The `FMX.Dialogs.InputBox()` and `FMX.Dialogs.InputQuery()` functions use `IFMXDialogService.InputQuery()` internally. On Android, `IFMXDialogService.InputQuery()` displays a standard Android [`AlertDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) with standard Android [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) controls on it.  It does not display a FireMonkey dialog with `TEdit` controls on it.  So it makes sense that Android's own dialog controls would respond to the keyboard since Android is doing all of the UI work.

Blackberry is not an officially supported platform, so there is probably a discrepancy between a "native" Android system and Blackberry's sandboxed Android system that FireMonkey does not like/recognize when it comes to handling hardware input.

Do you have the same problem with the touch-screen keyboard?

Comment: Haven't been able to test with a Full-touch BB, since I don't own one. TEdits DO work on multiple Android-devices (tablets and phones). BB Q10 doesn't have a touch-screen keyboard (or do I miss something ?).

Comment: Since blackberry-update OS10 v10.3 (roll-out since 19-2-2015), Android emulator captures all keyboard-strokes. Tried it with my own apk's (which were missing the keyboard-input), they all work now. Problem solved, thanks to Blackberry itself :-)